# How to bin rows into 10 minutes interval?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Assume this is my sample data:

```
         ID     datetime           
0         2  2015-01-09 19:05:39   
1         1  2015-01-10 20:33:38   
2         1  2015-01-10 20:33:38   
3         1  2015-01-10 20:45:39   
4         1  2015-01-10 20:46:39     
5         1  2015-01-10 20:46:59   
6         1  2015-01-10 20:50:39
```

I want to create a new column "BIN" which tells us which 10 minute bin this row belongs to.

i.e) Select minimum datetime and start from there. In this example data first row is the minimum time but it's not the case which my real data. My real data is not sorted.

```
         ID     datetime           bin 
0         2  2015-01-09 19:05:39   1
1         1  2015-01-10 20:33:38   2
2         1  2015-01-10 20:33:38   2
3         1  2015-01-10 20:45:39   3
4         1  2015-01-10 20:46:39   3  
5         1  2015-01-10 20:46:59   3
6         1  2015-01-10 20:50:39   3
```

Comment: It's not very clear from you example what the `bin` column is. 1-3 does not seem accurate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First subtract minimum value of `datetime` for timedeltas, then create `10minutes` values by [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html), then [`Series.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) and last convert to integers by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

df['bin'] = (df['datetime'].sub(df['datetime'].min())
                           .dt.floor('10Min')
                           .rank(method='dense')
                           .astype(int))
print (df)
   ID            datetime  bin
0   2 2015-01-09 19:05:39    1
1   1 2015-01-10 20:33:38    2
2   1 2015-01-10 20:33:38    2
3   1 2015-01-10 20:45:39    3
4   1 2015-01-10 20:46:39    3
5   1 2015-01-10 20:46:59    3
6   1 2015-01-10 20:50:39    3
```

Comment: can you tell me how to write this for dask dataframe. When I try to do it I get series object has no attribute rank error.

Comment: @user_12 - try alternative `df['bin'] = pd.factorize(df['datetime'].sub(df['datetime'].min()).dt.floor('10Min'))[0] + 1`

Comment: Thank you I was able to get both of them to work. Can you explain what the first code is doing step by step. What is floor is doing here and why is it used? and rank? It would really help if you explain it. I couldn't understand the pandas docs.

Comment: @user_12 - So  floor is used for rounding special way - it convert datetimes for first `10Min` datetime below, `rank` is used for ranking by position, so first values are 1, next 2... It working here similar like factorize.

Answer (score 2):

If you dataframe is called `df`. Assuming the bins you are referring to range from `1 - 6`, where 1 is between `0 - 10` minutes and 6 between `50 - 60`, then you can use the following formula:

```
import math

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df['bin'] = math.ceil(df['datetime'].minute / 10)
```